# Some new version of opencv_performance for opencv_traincascade?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have noted that the cascades trained with the program `opencv_traincascade` does not run with the current version of `opencv_performance`. I've tried to convert the old performance cpp file to load the new types of cascades, but without success. The code is here:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef PATH_MAX
#define PATH_MAX 512
#endif /* PATH_MAX */

/*typedef struct HidCascade {
 int size;
 int count;
 } HidCascade;
 */

typedef struct ObjectPos {
    float x;
    float y;
    float width;
    int found; /* for reference */
    int neghbors;
} ObjectPos;

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i, j;
    char* classifierdir = NULL;
    //char* samplesdir    = NULL;

    int saveDetected = 1;
    double scale_factor = 1.1;
    float maxSizeDiff = 1.5F;
    float maxPosDiff = 1.1F;

    /* number of stages. if <=0 all stages are used */
    //int nos = -1, nos0;
    int width = 25;
    int height = 15;

    int rocsize;

    FILE* info;
    FILE* resultados;
    char* infoname;
    char fullname[PATH_MAX];
    //char detfilename[PATH_MAX];
    char* filename;
    //char detname[] = "det-";

    CascadeClassifier cascade;

    double totaltime;

    if (!(resultados = fopen("resultados.txt", "w"))) {
        printf("Cannot create results file.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    infoname = (char*) "";
    rocsize = 20;
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Usage: %s\n  -data <classifier_directory_name>\n"
                "  -info <collection_file_name>\n"
                "  [-maxSizeDiff <max_size_difference = %f>]\n"
                "  [-maxPosDiff <max_position_difference = %f>]\n"
                "  [-sf <scale_factor = %f>]\n"
                "  [-ni]\n"
                "  [-rs <roc_size = %d>]\n"
                "  [-w <sample_width = %d>]\n"
                "  [-h <sample_height = %d>]\n", argv[0], maxSizeDiff,
                maxPosDiff, scale_factor, rocsize, width, height);

        return 0;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-data")) {
            classifierdir = argv[++i];
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-info")) {
            infoname = argv[++i];
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-maxSizeDiff")) {
            maxSizeDiff = (float) atof(argv[++i]);
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-maxPosDiff")) {
            maxPosDiff = (float) atof(argv[++i]);
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-sf")) {
            scale_factor = atof(argv[++i]);
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-ni")) {
            saveDetected = 0;
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-rs")) {
            rocsize = atoi(argv[++i]);
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-w")) {
            width = atoi(argv[++i]);
        } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-h")) {
            height = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }
    }

    if (!cascade.load(classifierdir)) {
        printf("Unable to load classifier from %s\n", classifierdir);
        return 1;
    }

    strcpy(fullname, infoname);
    filename = strrchr(fullname, '\\');
    if (filename == NULL) {
        filename = strrchr(fullname, '/');
    }
    if (filename == NULL) {
        filename = fullname;
    } else {
        filename++;
    }

    info = fopen(infoname, "r");
    totaltime = 0.0;

    if (info != NULL) {

        int x, y, width, height;
        Mat img;
        int hits, missed, falseAlarms;
        int totalHits, totalMissed, totalFalseAlarms;
        int found;
        float distance;

        int refcount;
        ObjectPos* ref;
        int detcount;
        ObjectPos* det;
        int error = 0;

        int* pos;
        int* neg;

        pos = (int*) cvAlloc(rocsize * sizeof(*pos));
        neg = (int*) cvAlloc(rocsize * sizeof(*neg));
        for (i = 0; i < rocsize; i++) {
            pos[i] = neg[i] = 0;
        }

        printf("+================================+======+======+======+\n");
        printf("|            File Name           | Hits |Missed| False|\n");
        printf("+================================+======+======+======+\n");
        fprintf(resultados,
                "+================================+======+======+======+\n");
        fprintf(resultados,
                "|            File Name           | Hits |Missed| False|\n");
        fprintf(resultados,
                "+================================+======+======+======+\n");
        //fprintf (resultados, "%d\n",framesCnt);

        totalHits = totalMissed = totalFalseAlarms = 0;
        while (!feof(info)) {
            fscanf(info, "%s %d", filename, &refcount);
            img = imread(fullname);

            if (!img.data) {
                cout << "ow" << endl;
                return -1;
            }
            ref = (ObjectPos*) cvAlloc(refcount * sizeof(*ref));
            for (i = 0; i < refcount; i++) {
                error = (fscanf(info, "%d %d %d %d", &x, &y, &width, &height)
                        != 4);
                if (error)
                    break;
                ref[i].x = 0.5F * width + x;
                ref[i].y = 0.5F * height + y;
                ref[i].width = sqrt(0.5F * (width * width + height * height));
                ref[i].found = 0;
                ref[i].neghbors = 0; //in the new cascade, where to get the neighbors?
            }

            vector<Rect> obj_detectados;
            Rect retang;
            if (!error) {
                totaltime -= time(0);

                cascade.detectMultiScale(img, obj_detectados, scale_factor, 4, 0
                //|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
                // |CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
                        | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(25, 15));

                totaltime += time(0);

                if (obj_detectados.size() == 0) {
                    detcount = 0;
                } else {
                    detcount = obj_detectados.size();
                }

                det = (detcount > 0) ?
                        ((ObjectPos*) cvAlloc(detcount * sizeof(*det))) : NULL;
                hits = missed = falseAlarms = 0;

                for (vector<Rect>::const_iterator r = obj_detectados.begin();
                        r != obj_detectados.end(); r++, i++) {
                    Point r1, r2;

                    r1.x = (r->x);
                    r1.y = (r->y);
                    r2.x = (r->x + r->width);
                    r2.y = (r->y + r->height);

                    retang.x = r1.x;
                    retang.y = r1.y;
                    retang.width = abs(r2.x - r1.x);
                    retang.height = abs(r2.y - r1.y);

                    if (saveDetected) {
                        rectangle(img, retang, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, CV_AA);
                    }

                    det[i].x = 0.5F*r->width + r->x;
                    det[i].y = 0.5F*r->height + r->y;
                    det[i].width = sqrt(0.5F * (r->width * r->width
                             + r->height * r->height));
                    det[i].neghbors = 1; // i don't know if it will work...
                     // det[i].neghbors = r.neighbors; --- how to do it in the new version??

                    found = 0;
                    for (j = 0; j < refcount; j++) {
                        distance = sqrtf( (det[i].x - ref[j].x) * (det[i].x - ref[j].x) +
                                (det[i].y - ref[j].y) * (det[i].y - ref[j].y) );
                        //cout << distance << endl;
                        if( (distance < ref[j].width * maxPosDiff) &&
                            (det[i].width > ref[j].width / maxSizeDiff) &&
                            (det[i].width < ref[j].width * maxSizeDiff) )
                        {
                            ref[j].found = 1;
                            ref[j].neghbors = MAX( ref[j].neghbors, det[i].neghbors );
                            found = 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!found) {
                        falseAlarms++;
                        neg[MIN(det[i].neghbors, rocsize - 1)]++;
                        //neg[MIN(0, rocsize - 1)]++;
                    }
                }
                //imshow("teste", img);
                if (saveDetected) {
                    //strcpy(detfilename, detname);
                    //strcat(detfilename, filename);
                    //strcpy(filename, detfilename);
                    imwrite(fullname, img);
                    //cvvSaveImage(fullname, img);
                }

                for (j = 0; j < refcount; j++) {
                    if (ref[j].found) {
                        hits++;
                        //pos[MIN(0, rocsize - 1)]++;
                        pos[MIN(ref[j].neghbors, rocsize - 1)]++;
                    } else {
                        missed++;
                    }
                }

                totalHits += hits;
                totalMissed += missed;
                totalFalseAlarms += falseAlarms;
                printf("|%32.64s|%6d|%6d|%6d|\n", filename, hits, missed,
                        falseAlarms);
                //printf("+--------------------------------+------+------+------+\n");
                fprintf(resultados, "|%32.64s|%6d|%6d|%6d|\n", filename, hits,
                        missed, falseAlarms);
                //fprintf(resultados,
                //      "+--------------------------------+------+------+------+\n");
                fflush(stdout);

                if (det) {
                    cvFree( &det);
                    det = NULL;
                }
            } /* if( !error ) */

            //char c = (char) waitKey(10);
            //              if (c == 27)
            //                  exit(0);

            cvFree( &ref);
        }
        fclose(info);

        printf("|%32.32s|%6d|%6d|%6d|\n", "Total", totalHits, totalMissed,
                totalFalseAlarms);
        fprintf(resultados, "|%32.32s|%6d|%6d|%6d|\n", "Total", totalHits,
                totalMissed, totalFalseAlarms);
        printf("+================================+======+======+======+\n");
        fprintf(resultados,
                "+================================+======+======+======+\n");
        //printf("Number of stages: %d\n", nos);
        //printf("Number of weak classifiers: %d\n", numclassifiers[nos - 1]);
        printf("Total time: %f\n", totaltime);
        fprintf(resultados, "Total time: %f\n", totaltime);

        /* print ROC to stdout */
        for (i = rocsize - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            pos[i - 1] += pos[i];
            neg[i - 1] += neg[i];
        }
        //fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", nos);
        for (i = 0; i < rocsize; i++) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\t%d\t%d\t%f\t%f\n", pos[i], neg[i],
                    ((float) pos[i]) / (totalHits + totalMissed),
                    ((float) neg[i]) / (totalHits + totalMissed));
        }

        cvFree( &pos);
        cvFree( &neg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My doubt is about the `det[i].neghbors = r.neighbors;` in the old performance.cpp. How I retrieve the neighbors in this new version?

Anyone could help me to convert `opencv_performance` to run the new cascades from `opencv_traincascade`?

Many thanks!

Comment: My program runs, but I think that it have a problem with memory management. It process some images (two or three) and stops. It should have processed more images (for example, 100 images). The `vector <Rect>` maybe part of the problem?

Comment: Update: I have found a bug, on the for loop that iterates the vector<Rect>, I forgot to put i=0 before the loop. So the memory problem is solved.